# Количество единичных битов

Tags: битовые-операции, java

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос.

Необходимо подсчитать количество единичных битов в числе типа int (java). Одним из решений, например, есть метод (из статьи на одном сайте про побитовые операции):

```
public int bitCounter(int n) {
int counter = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    counter += n & 1;
    n = n >>> 1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Тут все понятно: проверяем младший бит побитовым и с 1 и после сдвигаем биты вправо с заполнением нулями, в итоге доходим до нуля и получаем количество 1 битов.

И вот в статье дальше идет еще более улучшенное решение, не могу его понять в одном месте:

```
public int bitCounter(int n) {
int count = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    count++;
    n = n & (n - 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Написано: "Для этого рассмотрим выражение число (n - 1). Это число, отличается от n тем, что вместо последнего единичного бита у него 0, а все последующие биты равны 1".

Собственно здесь не могу понять. Ну n = 5 или n = 0b101 и n-1 = 4 или n-1 = 0b100, то есть 101 и 100.

Я не вижу цитирую "отличается от n тем, что вместо последнего единичного бита у него 0, а все последующие биты равны 1". Младший бит равен 0 у четверки, но следующий тоже 0 а не 1.

Где-то я туплю, но я не понимаю, как n = n & (n - 1) работает. По выражению count++ очевидно, что при каждой итерации у нас гарантированно получается отсчитать единичный бит.

Подскажите, в чем суть, и извините за стену текста.

Comment: Если верить [Интернету](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan), этот метод использовал ещё Керниган, а известен вообще с 1960-го года.

Comment: Ну так цитату я привел со статьи.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Последний единичный бит - первый **не нулевой** с конца,  а не вообще первый с конца. При таком цикле пропускаются нули, а на каждой итерации зануляется ровно один бит с конца:

```
10101
10100 = 10101 & 10100
10000 = 10100 & 10011
0
```

Comment: Про последний понял, про операцию & тоже понятно, но все равно в целом не до конца. Сдвигать вправо и сравнивать младший бит & 1 в голове очевидно воспринимается. 

Выходит что (n-1) это тоже что и n, но последний единичный бит здесь 0, а поскольку после операции & в таком случае - этот 0 из числа (n-1) и единичный бит из n даст всегда 0, то мы грубо говоря откусываем на каждой итерации 1 единичный бит(который последний у числа n заменяя его 0, пока не превратим все в 0). Правильно я понял?)

Answer (score 1):

"Собственно здесь не могу понять. Ну n = 5 или n = 0b101 и n-1 = 4 или n-1 = 0b100, то есть 101 и 100. Я не вижу цитирую "отличается от n тем, что вместо последнего единичного бита у него 0, а все последующие биты равны 1". Младший бит равен 0 у четверки, но следующий тоже 0 а не 1."

Данный пример не общий, поэтому возникли трудности. Когда вычитается единица из n, то последний единичный бит инвертируется. В этом примере  10**1** -> 10**0**. И так как правее единичного бита больше нет битов, то больше ничего не инвертируется. Если же рассмотреть другой пример, например 1100, то n-1 будет 1011: 1**1**00 -> 1**011**. Здесь уже видно, что все правые биты инвертируются.
Соответственно если применим **&** к n и n-1, то каждую итерацию получаем новое число, которое имеет на один единичный бит меньше, так как все биты, начиная с последнего единичного бита у числа n инвертированы по отношению к числу n-1. Таким образом, подсчитываем общее количество единиц.